# MathJax not rendering in Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, mathjax

I have a documentation set in Sphinx reST.
I've included sphinx.ext.mathjax in conf.py, and included the line "mathjax_path = 'http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js'".
I believe that is all I need to do before adding markup to the rst files. But my equations aren't being rendered. For example,

```
:math:`a^2 + b^2 = c^2`
```

comes out of the browser as

```
\(a^2 + b^2 = c^2\)
```

No fancy font or anything. The HTML is

```
<span class="math">\(a^2 + b^2 = c^2\)</span>
```

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your post for future readers).

Answer (score 6):

You still need to declare the extention to sphinx-doc in the conf.py file.

On the top of the conf.py file, soon after `import sys, os` under "general configuration" you will see the comments notes about including extentions. For mathjax you need to add it to the listed extension:

```
 # Add any Sphinx extension module names here, as strings. They can be extensions
 # coming with Sphinx (named 'sphinx.ext.*') or your custom ones.
 extensions = ['sphinx.ext.todo', 'sphinx.ext.mathjax', 'sphinx.ext.ifconfig']
```

(I've just copy pasted my own, you may have other or no extentions listed there at the moment).

That in combination with the mathjax_path that you have already set should work.

Comment: @caduceus and you are sure that you have a working internet connection.... just checking because otherwise you will need to download mathjax and give a local path for it to work.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. I solved it by setting the mathjax_path variable (on the conf.py file) as:

```
mathjax_path="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"
```

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.

Answer (score 3):

Here there are some options:

1. You must install libjs-mathjax:

```
    apt-get install libjs-mathjax
```

2. You should put a "r" prefixing documentations lines:

```
    r"""
      :math:`a^2 + b^2 = c^2`

    """
```

3. You must avoid spaces in the equation (with "r" prefix you avoid this solution)

```
   """
     :math:`a^2+b^2=c^2`

   """
```

4. You could mix all the previous solution

```
    r"""
      :math:`a^2+b^2=c^2`

    """
```