# Is there any MathML support in Sphinx (by mathjax extension)?

Tags: python-sphinx, mathjax

Is there anyway to render MathML in the rst file with Sphinx?

I enabled mathjax extension in conf.py. It works very well with latex using like

[image]

However, if I replace it with math ML, it does render it but instead display all the xml code. For example,

[image]

produces

[image]

In Sphinx math is rendered by a mathjax extension. On https://www.mathjax.org/ mathjax claims they support MathML.

Comment: Did you try to configure it? What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @StevePiercy I tried to add a line mathjax_path="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML" in conf.py (found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19655706/mathjax-not-rendering-in-sphinx). Does not work for me..

Comment: You forgot the protocol, `https://`, in `mathjax_path` value.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer without knowing your desired output, but from the [doc](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#math)

> The "math" directive inserts blocks with mathematical content (display
>   formulas, equations) into the document. **The input format is LaTeX math
>   syntax** with support for Unicode symbols

So, no way to use MMl with `..math::`
If you output in HTML, you can try [raw](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#raw-data-pass-through) or [literal](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#literal-blocks) directives instead to let the block as is. The block will be displayed correctly in a MML browser compliant. If you include mathjax libraries with a correct configuration it will also process.